# Invalid link in RSS

Tags: php, rss

I'm working on a RSS feed but i can't validate it,b ecause of an invalid link.

The problem is that the link includes square brackets.

Link:

```
http://www.url.com/index.php?no_cache=1&tx_syvin_pi1[param1]=123456789&tx_syvin_pi1[param2]=123
```

I already tried to replace the [] with %5B and %5D, didn't work. I also tried urlencode, didn't work.

RSS version is 2.0, encoding is utf-8

Comment: i think will be a simple xml file link? like sitename.com/myxmlfeed.xml

Comment: there is no problem on this link. that `[]` is just a grouping name, so that it can take several parameters in the same name. much like an array

Comment: Oh sorry, i might have explained it wrong. The link isn't the link to the rss feed, it's the <link> field inside the feed

Comment: Got it, putting the link in CDATA was the fix.